# Как правильно скопировать 10 элементов из массива list [], в массивы array [],array2[]? Я так понимаю должны быть специальные методы?

Tags: java, массивы

`int list[]=new int[20];
int array[]=new int[10];
int array2[]=new int[10];`

Comment: в цикле! а как вы подругому хотите?

Comment: Если бы я хоть как то могла,то сделала бы...мне,в принципе, нужно понять каким образом этот процесс происходит. Чтоб и говнокод не писать,и чтоб правильно было...

Comment: а вы подумайте!

Answer (score 2):

Копирование в цикле не рекомендую - много кода и есть шанс допустить ошибку. Переводить в коллекцию аналогично - только лишние объекты без толку плодить. У JAVA из коробки есть способы копировать массивы. В вашем случае подойдет такой :

```
System.arraycopy(list, 0, array, 0, 10);
System.arraycopy(list, 10, array2, 0, 10);
```

Кроме того, существует Arrays.copyOf(). Разница в том, что в последний передается только исходный массив, а уже метод возвращает новый скопированный. В вашем случае целевой массив уже существует, поэтому используем System.arraycopy(), у него тип возвращаемого значения VOID, потому как оба массива (из которого копируется и в который копируется) передаются в аргументы метода.

Comment: Спасибо огромное..теперь мне понятно)

Comment: @Gomonova да не за что, пользуйтесь и радуйтесь

Comment: Ирония в том, что под капотом arraycopy те же циклы. Но в целом, согласен с вами в том, что новичек может с легкостью допустить ошибку

Comment: @  Circassian у спринга под капотом в вебе сервлеты, а  хибернейт сырые sql бросает. мы же не отказываемся от спринга, хотя магии там нет)) а вот в данном конкретном случае вы сильно ошибаетесь. System.arraycopy не содержит никаких циклов, он реализован нативно, а посему обгнонит ваши циклы с легкостью. аналогично и Arrays.copyOf, который под капотом делегирует выполнение System.arraycopy. нет там циклов в сорцах и никогда не было))

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int n = list[i];
    if (i < 10) {
        array[i] = n;
    } else {
        array2[i] = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Код для примера, но его можно еще дополнить проверками, чтоб не поймать IndexOutOfBoundsException